# YoutubeAPI returns 401 Invalid Credentials error when try to upload video to youtube using Youtube Data API(V3)

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload video to Youtube using Angular File Uploader,OAuth and Youtube Data API(v3) in Codeigniter project. But It always fails with 401 Invalid Credentials response. I tried creating a youtube channel as suggested by other answer but it didn't work for me.

This is my POST url structure

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?client_id={clientID}&access_token={accessToken}&part=snippet&mine=true`

Please can someone explain me the procedure for do this successfully I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid Credentials means that The access token you're using is either expired or invalid. You should check the full error for more information.  It normally looks something like this.

> 401: [Invalid Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) Invalid authorization header.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

[Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) is a public request this means that technically  you only need an API key.

> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?key=yourkey

You can use an access_token which was gained from Oauth2 authencation.

> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?access_token=yourtoken

There is no need to add client_id this may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: even if only access token it fails.